# How to manually trigger file reader onerror event?

Tags: javascript

I'm testing all the scenarios on reading files using `new FileReader();`
When the read is done, onload() should be triggered.
I have no idea how to trigger `onerror()` callback
Any idea?

```
        var promise = Promise.create();
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function () {
        };
        fileReader.onerror = function(event) {
            // I want to stay here ..........
            // Who can tell me how to trigger this onerror callback?
            debugger
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(inputFile);
        return promise;
```

Comment: Maybe permissions?

Comment: You have to mock the FileReader. If you tell me which libraries are you using for testing maybe I can help you-

Comment: I'm coding on the REAL code. Just want have a quick test for now. Is it possible to trigger this without any testing lib or mock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simply calling abort:

```
var promise = Promise.create();
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function () {
  fileReader.abort()
};
fileReader.onerror = function(event) {
  // I want to stay here ..........
  // Who can tell me how to trigger this onerror callback?
  debugger
};
fileReader.readAsText(inputFile);
return promise;
```

If that doesn't work you can try a [permissions](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#ErrorAndException) error with something like:

```sh
touch testfile
chmod 000 testfile
```

And open that file from your reader.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're trying to find out is how to use Async functions:

```
async function FileReader(){
    // your code for the file reading
  return;
};
```

then use await in your `onload()` function to wait for it to return:

```
async function onload(){
  await firstFunction();  // This waits for fileReader() function to finish...
  // do what you want to show when fileReading is done
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much~ would you please take a look for my update?

Comment: By the way, any chance to find all possible exceptions? Didn't find it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/error

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in debugger mode and add a breakpoint at line "fileReader.readAsText(inputFile)". When the debugger stops, you rename manually the file in your filesystem. FileReader then throws an error.
The accepted answer doesn't work in my environment.